Getting error while dealing with aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls
I have created an s3 bucket and planning to create a website in the bucket. before that i have given the public access by below command. But i am getting error while running plan command.


Error
A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

What is the cause of this error?
The same thing have mentioned in Simple DevOps Project to Practice Terraform with AWS - YouTube at 10:43.
I cross-checked the reference video and the provider connection as well. Still getting error.

Can you add the text of your code instead of a screenshot? It helps with debugging. Also, can you provide your provider configuration?
